# How does #value_callback really work (nested elements, ...)?

Tags: 7, forms

**EDIT: [Separated 4th question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125885/when-to-use-value-callback-and-when-element-validate).**

I've just recently started working with custom elements and already came across some weird behavior / questions I'd like to see answered.

**1)** How does `#value_callback` work, what should you return in it, etc. ?

Imagine you have pretty simple custom element without set `#element_validate`:

```
function TST_element_process($element, &$form_statem, $form) {
  $element['testing_test'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => 'ABC',
  );

  return $element;
}
function TST_value_callback_1($element, $input = FALSE, &$form_state) {
  //example of input retrieving magic
  return ($input['testing_test'] . '_valc_');
}
function TST_value_callback_2($element, $input = FALSE, &$form_state) {
  //example of input retrieving magic
  return array($input['testing_test'] . '_valc_');
}

'TST' => array(
  '#input' => TRUE,
  '#tree' => TRUE,
  '#process' => array('TST_element_process'),
  //'#element_validate' => array('TST_element_validate'),
  '#value_callback' => 'TST_value_callback_1', // or TST_value_callback_2
),
```

And form:

```
$ar['inp'] = array('#type' => 'TST');
```

*1A)* When you use `TST_value_callback_1`, the callback gets called and runs but doesn't alter the result value in any way (in submit the `$form_state['values']['inp']['testing_test']` contains pure input -> `ABC`).

*1B)* In case of `TST_value_callback_2` the `$form_state['values']['inp']['testing_test']` still contains unaltered input but there's also value in `$form_state['values']['inp'][0]` which contains the 'right' value (`ABC_valc_`).

My questions are:

**1.1** what exactly are you supposed to return in `#value_callback` and why do the individual callbacks work in the way they do (or don't do in case of the first one).

**1.2** is there any way how to make the `#value_callback` store the data in 'element root' (`$form_state['values']['inp']`), i.e. in the same place as if I used form_set_value in `#element_validate`?

---

**2)** How do individual `#value_callback` work on custom element that is made of other elements?

Let's say you have a custom element (`A`) that is made of a nested set of other elements with set `#value_callback`.

```
for($a = 0; $a < 10; $a++) {
  $element['indiv_elems'][] = array(
    '#type' => 'indiv_element',
  );
}
```

Then a number of things can appear in `$form_state[values][<element_name_in_FAPI_array>]` depending on how you approach `#value_callback` in the custom event (`A`) (and some of those things make little sense to me).

*2A)* When you don't use `#value_callback` in (`A`) at all, the `$form_state[values][<element_name_in_FAPI_array>]` will contain array of raw inputs (not processed by its `#value_callback` function) from each `phone_numbers` element.

*2B)* When you set `#value_callback` in (`A`) but let it return (let's say) empty array(), the `$form_state[values][<element_name_in_FAPI_array>]` will contain array of  inputs from each `indiv_element` element processed by their (individual  `#value_callback` function) .

My question is:

**2.1**) Why do the values not get processed by individual `#value_callback` when parent element's `#value_callback` is not set. Basically why is there difference between *2A)* and *2B)*.

---

**3)** Do I understand [this flowchart](https://www.drupal.org/files/fapi_workflow_7.x_v1.1.png)  correctly that `#value_callback` is called before `#element_validate`?

---

I'm also aware that it will be quite time consuming to answer this question, so many thanks and love ahead! :)

Comment: I think I can help with 2) & 3). 1) seems a bit weird to me - could you post your value callback?

Comment: @Andy I've actually found out it didn't work exactly as I wrote. So I added (quite large) edit section near the end.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show where in the form this element is? If it's not in the root of the form, try putting it there and see if that changes anything. Also, looking at Q4 I think it would really help if you could be concrete in what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Whether it is in the root or not doesn't make any difference. Tried it. As for 4) question, I've updated it along with rewriting the first one. 
//Thanks for help, btw :)

Comment: @Petrroll Can you add your `hook_element_info()` too so it make more sense how you adding `#value_callback`.

Comment: @MutantMahesh Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing i want to add before replying to your questions. Drupal core FAPI doesn't allow multiple `#value_callback`. It allow only one `#value_callback` per element type. Even You don't have to add `#value_callback` key in your `hook_element_info()` if your value callback follow the format `form_type_' . $element['#type'] . '_value'`.

```
// See code in include/form.inc from function _form_builder_handle_input_element line 2034

$value_callback = !empty($element['#value_callback']) ? $element['#value_callback'] : 'form_type_' . $element['#type'] . '_value';
```

***1)** How does `#value_callback` work, what should you return in it, etc. ?*

> value_callback provides a way to process values before they are returned to the form submit function. You need to provide a `#value_callback` if you want to do fancy processing on the input. If you just want #value set to #default_value, you don't need this hook at all, since that will happen anyway. This function is mainly useful if you need to do something non-standard with the value, like transpose an array into an option list.
>
> Value callbacks should consider three conditions:

1. Input is being provided directly. This happens when a form is submitted.
2. No input is provided, but the field definition has a default value.
3. No input is provided and there is no default value.

***1.1)** what exactly are you supposed to return in #value_callback and why do the individual callbacks work in the way they do (or don't do in case of the first one).*

So value callback is supposed to check the `$input !== FALSE` and then modify the `$input` value as per your logic. If its false that means `$input` value is not provided in this case you can return the `$element['#defalut_value']`. So in your first value callback `TST_value_callback_1` if you want to make that work you have to return the value with the **same array key** something like.

```
function TST_value_callback_1($element, $input = FALSE, &$form_state) {
  //example of input retrieving magic
  $input['testing_test'] = $input['testing_test'] . '_valc_';
  return $input;
}
```

In your **second value callback** `TST_value_callback_2`  it was adding value to `$form_state['values']['inp'][0]` because you was returning an array with index 0 having the value `ABC_valc_` like `array(0 => 'ABC_valc_');`

```
// code from include/form.inc from function _form_builder_handle_input_element line 2109

// Set the element's value in $form_state['values'], but only, if its key
// does not exist yet (a #value_callback may have already populated it).
if (!drupal_array_nested_key_exists($form_state['values'], $element['#parents'])) {
  form_set_value($element, $element['#value'], $form_state);
}
```

***1.2** is there any way how to make the #value_callback store the data in 'element root' ($form_state['values']['inp']), i.e. in the same place as if I used form_set_value in #element_validate?*

Setting the `#tree` to `false` in your form element should do the trick.

```
$ar['inp'] = array(
  '#type' => 'TST',
  '#tree' => FALSE,
  );
```

you will be able to get the value in `$form_state['values']['inp']` but in this case `#value_callback` will not do any affect, and `$input` in `#value_callback` is set to `NULL`  i don't know why. So you better use the `($form_state['values']['inp']['testing_test'])`

***2.1)** Is there any way to enable 2.2 behavior without setting #value_callback in ?*

***2.2)** Why are individual #value_callback functions run (and their outputs are saved to $form_state) only when parent (A) #value_callback is run (even if it doesn't reference or call the individual functions in any way)?*

Hopefully my above explanation help you to understand the role of `#value_callback`. Even though custom element that is made of a nested set of other elements, are also elements so individual value callback will be called for each subelement. There is too much too explain Please take a look at [_form_builder_handle_input_element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/_form_builder_handle_input_element/7)

***3)** Do I understand this flowchart correctly that #value_callback is called before #element_validate?*

yes `#value_callback` is called before the `#element_validate` callback. For more explanation See [Creating Custom Elements](https://www.drupal.org/node/169815)

For practical example see [examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module.

See also:

https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example%21form_example_elements.inc/function/form_type_form_example_checkbox_value/7

https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example%21form_example_elements.inc/function/form_example_phonenumber_combined_value/7

Comment: Thanks, it makes a bit more sense now. Especially the link to _form_builder_handle_input_element helped a lot. I'd still like to understand the idea behind  #value_callback and where does it stand in comparison to #element_validate (more in linked question 4) because I wasn't able to find any useful use of #value_callback (examples, date module, ...) apart from processing #default_value.

Comment: And considering 2.2) it still doesn't explain why individual callbacks are not called when 'parent' callback is called. As I understood it, they should be independent.

Comment: @Petrroll If you can refine question 2.1 and 2.2 and make it more clear then may be i can add something more to my answer.

Comment: Done, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: BTW: Considering 1.1. As you saw yourself in 1B you don't have to return value with the same array key. Looking into core code I can't find anything that would say you have to either. So the question why the value is not altered in 1A still stays.

Comment: I've tried to look into how core works and probably found some interesting things (my observations might have been slightly wrong). So ignore questions under 2) for the time being. 

1) (explained in last comment) still intrigues me, though.

Comment: It is not so complex, `#value_callback` is intended to modify the `$input` values at existing array key if `$input !== FALSE` otherwise return the `#default_value` rest  `function _form_builder_handle_input_element` will handle. Of course it is not explicitly mentioned that you should return the value with `same array key` But magic happens at the end of function where ` form_set_value($element, $element['#value'], $form_state);` is called which in turns call the `drupal_array_set_nested_value` It will not set the value properly if $element['#parents'] are not properly mentioned.

Comment: But AFAIK the #parents property of the element (which is used in set_element_value) is not altered by the key I use in return of #value_callback (at least nowhere in _form_builder_handle_input_element says it is). So again, where is the problem?

BTW: I've cracked down the problem with 2) :).

Comment: Ok, I've found possible reason why you can't return non-array in #value_callback. For some reason raw input of an element is added to  $form_state[values] at some point which requires the $form_state[values]<elementparents> to be an array. It must happen somewhere between _form_builder_handle_input_element (not present there) and #element_validate (when you use form_set_value there, you can overwrite it). So my question is, where does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

2) The problem lied in the fact that individual `#value_callback`s get run after the (`A`)'s callback is run (the higher the element is, the sooner their callbacks get run (which is IMHO counter intuitive)).

Therefore, when the `#value_callback` of (`A`) is not set, default behavior happens which means that raw input from all individual sub-elements is set as element's value (in $form_state) in the end of [_form_builder_handle_input_element](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/_form_builder_handle_input_element/7).

And finally when individual `#value_callback` get run (and they get run) their outputs can't be stored in $form_state[values] because of the fact that the place is already occupied by (above mentioned) individual elements' raw input.

```
  // Set the element's value in $form_state['values'], but only, if its key
  // does not exist yet (a #value_callback may have already populated it).
  if (!drupal_array_nested_key_exists($form_state['values'], $element['#parents'])) {
    form_set_value($element, $element['#value'], $form_state);
  }
```